# Find and compare cell values for each row in a table

Tags: jquery, html

I've got two similar tables that have cells that contain values (1-99, or empty). In each row, I need to see if the values of two cells are equal. If they are, a checkmarks is displayed in another cell. The first value (number) comes from counting certain values in another table, the second value (match) is hard coded.

The code below works for the first table: matches are found, and checkmarks are displayed correctly. For the second table however, it doesn't work: for some reason the code compares the values of the first table (numberA) with the matching values of the second table (matchB), and then displays the checkmarks in checkitB accordingly.

First table:

```
<table class="myNumbers_tableA">
    <tr class="myNumbers_trA">
        <td class="numberA" id='numberA_pdc'></td>
        <td>This happened <span class="matchA" id="matchA_pdc">3</span> times</td>
        <td class="checkitA" id="checkitA_pdc"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myNumbers_trA">
        <td class="numberA" id='numberA_boz'></td>
        <td>This happened <span class="matchA" id="matchA_boz">17</span> times</td>
        <td class="checkitA" id="checkitA_boz"></td>
    </tr>

etc.

</table>
```

Second table:

```
<table class="myNumbers_tableB">
    <tr class="myNumbers_trB">
        <td class="numberB" id='numberB_zwp'></td>
        <td>This happened <span class="matchB" id="matchB_zwp">58</span> times</td>
        <td class="checkitB" id="checkitB_zwp"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myNumbers_trB">
        <td class="numberB" id='numberB_ipc'></td>
        <td>This happened <span class="matchB" id="matchB_ipc">2</span> times</td>
        <td class="checkitB" id="checkitB_ipc"></td>
    </tr>

etc.

</table>
```

Code for the first table:

```
$('.checkitA').html(function() {
    var find_numberA = $(this).closest('tr.myNumbers_trA').find('.numberA').text();
    var find_matchA = $(this).closest('tr.myNumbers_trA').find('.matchA').text();
    return parseInt(find_numberA, 10) == parseInt(find_matchA, 10) ? '&#10004;' : '';
});
```

Code for the second table:

```
$('.checkitB').html(function() {
    var find_numberB = $(this).closest('tr.myNumbers_trB').find('.numberB').text();
    var find_matchB = $(this).closest('tr.myNumbers_trB').find('.matchB').text();
    return parseInt(find_numberB, 10) == parseInt(find_matchB, 10) ? '&#10004;' : '';
});
```

I have tried various codes, but none seem to do what I want. I think it has something to do with closest(), but I don't know what should be used instead. Please advise! Thanks!

Another example that only works for the first table:

```
$('.checkitA').html(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr.myNumbers_trA');
    return parseInt(row.find('.numberA').text(), 10) == parseInt(row.find('.matchA').text(), 10) ? '&#10004;' : '';
});
```

**EDIT**: it works incorrectly both ways, so if there is a match in table B, the checkmark is also displayed in table A. So the problem is that the comparison is not limited to the parent tr.

**EDIT2**: this is what I expect, but in both tables both the first and the third row get a checkmark:

[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9LhI.png)

Comment: you can use .parent() to get the <tr> `var row = $(this).parent('.myNumbers_trA');` or just only `var row = $(this).parent()` if you want to know more about .parent() here the docs. https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: @Sim1-81 Thanks for the tip. I replaced closest() with parent() but the result is the same.

Comment: can you supply a working snippet of your code? also a screenshot of what you expect is helpful

Comment: i see there is no  `tr.myNumbers`  into your HTML they have respectively class `myNumbers_trA` and `myNumbers_trB`  also 'tr.matchesB' is wrong selector

Comment: Sorry, those were copy past errors.. I have edited the code to match the file I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below a snippet of a workaround. what i've done is check if the number within your span.checkitA is in contained into the string of the first cell of the same row. if occurrence occurs i put the check on the third cell of the same row. same for the "B" table.

to do that i use .parent() and .children() to know what row i'm checking and to grab the counter, then with .indexOf() i check if it is a substring of the text within the first cell.

```js
$('.checkitA, .checkitB').html(function() {

    var row = $(this).parent();
    var text_cell1 = row.children().eq(0).text();
    var text_cell2 = row.children().eq(1).find('span').text();
    
    if(text_cell1.indexOf(text_cell2) !== -1){
       $(this).text('&#10004;')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myNumbers_tableA">
    <tr class="myNumbers_trA">
        <td class="numberA" id='numberA_pdc'> Score of 3</td>
        <td>This happened <span class="matchA" id="matchA_pdc">3</span> times</td>
        <td class="checkitA" id="checkitA_pdc"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myNumbers_trA">
        <td class="numberA" id='numberA_boz'>score of 10</td>
        <td>This happened <span class="matchA" id="matchA_boz">17</span> times</td>
        <td class="checkitA" id="checkitA_boz"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br><br>
<table class="myNumbers_tableB">
    <tr class="myNumbers_trB">
        <td class="numberB" id='numberB_zwp'>score of 58</td>
        <td>This happened <span class="matchB" id="matchB_zwp">28</span> times</td>
        <td class="checkitB" id="checkitB_zwp"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myNumbers_trB">
        <td class="numberB" id='numberB_ipc'>score of 1</td>
        <td>This happened <span class="matchB" id="matchB_ipc">1</span> times</td>
        <td class="checkitB" id="checkitB_ipc"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

unfortunatelly this code match strings, so in the following case the script fails

```
<tr class="myNumbers_trA">
   <td class="numberA" id='numberA_pdc'> Score of 34</td>
   <td>This happened <span class="matchA" id="matchA_pdc">3</span> times</td>
   <td class="checkitA" id="checkitA_pdc"></td>
</tr>
```

because 3 is a substring of 34. Instead if you can wrap both numbers with a span with a little edit, the code will works fine.

to works properly with my solution your HTML code, (if possible) should turns into this

```
<tr class="myNumbers_trA">
       <td class="numberA" id='numberA_pdc'> Score of <span>34</span></td>
       <td>This happened <span class="matchA" id="matchA_pdc">3</span> times</td>
       <td class="checkitA" id="checkitA_pdc"></td>
    </tr>
```

anf JS becomes

```
$('.checkitA, .checkitB').html(function() {

    var row = $(this).parent();
    var text_cell1 = row.children().eq(0).find('span').text();
    var text_cell2 = row.children().eq(1).find('span').text();

    if(text_cell1 == text_cell2){
       $(this).text('&#10004;')
    }
});
```

in this way the code will match all numbers without errors.